# How to load iFrame in div by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I want load an iFrame in my `div` by AJAX. How can I do it?

```html
<button id="iframeload">Load Iframe</button>
<div id="iframe_content"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.iframeload').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url : "https://pecom.ru/ru/calc/?iframe=Y",
          success : function (data) {  
              // alert('ok');
              $("#iframe_content").html(data); 
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

This is the iFrame

```html
<iframe id="pecom-kabinet-iframe" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="800" height="1800" scrolling="auto" style="border: 0;" src="https://pecom.ru/ru/calc/?iframe=Y">Not supported browser< / iframe >
```

ANd the button `#iframeload` does not work...

Comment: Why an iframe? Could you not use a div and just append the response to that?

Answer (score 1):

**First Error**

You are using elements class, not it's id in your code:

```
<button id="iframeload">
$('.iframeload').click(function(event) {
```

**Second Error**

Looks like you want your ajax call to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons.

**Possible Solution**

However, if you just want to display the iframe content on button click, there is no need for ajax.

just use `attr('scr',url)`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#iframeload').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    
    var url = 'https://pecom.ru/ru/calc/?iframe=Y';
    
    $('#abc_frame').attr('src', url);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="iframeload">Load Iframe</button>
<div id="iframe_content">
  <iframe name="abc_frame" id="abc_frame" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.qries.com');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="iframe" name="myIframe" frameborder="5" width="500" height="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```